# How to map a cell value to another cell with IF condition

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

Suppose I have a table like this in excel -

```
+-------------+----------+------------+
| Google Name | D11 Name |   Entry    |
+-------------+----------+------------+
| REN         | MLR      |            |
| THU         | SDT      |            |
| SIX         | SDS      |            |
| HOH         | HBH      |            |
| STR         | ADS      |            |
| HEA         | BRH      |            |
| PRS         | PS       |            |
| STA         | MLS      |            |
+-------------+----------+------------+
```

Now I will enter something in `Entry` column. If the value matches with `Google Name` value it should change to corresponding `D11 Name` value. Which means this -

```
+-------------+----------+------------+
| Google Name | D11 Name |   Entry    |
+-------------+----------+------------+
| REN         | MLR      | SIX -> SDS |
| THU         | SDT      |            |
| SIX         | SDS      |            |
| HOH         | HBH      |            |
| STR         | ADS      |            |
| HEA         | BRH      |            |
| PRS         | PS       |            |
| STA         | MLS      |            |
+-------------+----------+------------+
```

If I enter `SIX` final entry will be `SDS`, `->` is for explaining purpose only.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change a typed input to a values retrieved from a lookup, you need VBA and a Worksheet_Change event driven sub procedure.

Open the worksheet's private code sheet (right-click worksheet name tab and View Code) then paste in this code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo sub_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim t As Range, m As Variant
        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Range("C:C"))
            m = Application.Match(t.Value2, Range("A:A"), 0)
            If Not IsError(m) Then
                t = Cells(m, "B").Value2
            End If
        Next t

    End If

sub_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

[image]